# mobile web slide-up menu using css3 and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, mobile

Basically I'm trying to create a slide up (from the bottom) menu that quickly and smoothly slides up into view as the user scrolls upwards toward the top of the page, but then quickly and smoothly slides out of view as they scroll downwards to continue reading. Much like the menu in the google+ android/ios app.

I wrote a tiny bit of javascript that sort of accomplishes this... however the animation is a choppy at best and doesn't play nicely with ios devices. I'm testing this on a nexus 4, iPhone 4, and an iPad 2. In ios devices, the menu only animates AFTER the scrolling comes to a complete stop - which isn't what I want at all yet I don't know how to fix that.

Would it be better to do a css3 approach? if so how would go about doing that? And is there a way I can ensure the animation happens while the user is scrolling rather than after it stops? Thanks!

here's my javascript code:

```
(function () {
    var previousScroll = 0;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
                $("#disappearing-footer").slideUp('fast');
            } else {
                $("#disappearing-footer").slideDown('fast');
        }
        previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}());
```

css:

```
 #disappearing-footer {
  background-color: #333333;    
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px
}
```

Comment: Here is a library https://github.com/harvesthq/Sidetap. see its demo there. And also it is very easy to use.

Comment: there are [issues with `position:fixed` on mobile safari](http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/)

Comment: thanks I'll look into sidetap, but it seems like it's only a framework for slide in facebook style menus? Unless there's more I'm not seeing.